# includes() and toLowerCase throws not a function error from jest unit test

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

MyComponent.js has toLowerCase and includes on the props. When I unit test MyComponent, I get toLowerCase and includes() is not a function.

MyComponent.js

`this.props.currentUser.role.toLowerCase().includes('admin')`

MyComponent.test.js

```
    mount(<Provider store={store}>
        <MyComponent />
      </Provider>);
  });
```

Error:

```
TypeError: this.props.currentUser.role.toLowerCase is not a function 
TypeError: this.props.currentUser.role.includes is not a function
```

Comment: Unrelated but this code this.props.currentUser.role.toLowerCase().includes('Admin') will always return false becouse you call .toLowerCase() and check if it contains Admin which has an uppercase letter

Answer (score 2):

You should pass the currentUser object as a prop to the component.

```
let user ={role:"test"}
mount(<Provider store={store}>
        <MyComponent currentUser={user}/>
      </Provider>);
});
```

Comment: thanks. I was actually mocking props incorrectly.
 But lowercase is still an issue.

const profileType = useSelector(state => state.companyInformation.company.profileType);
When I do console log for profileType, I can see the mocked value.

But profileType?.tolowerCase() gives issue.

ERROR:

TypeError: profileType.tolowerCase is not a function

Comment: What is the type of profileType? And I believe you are not using tolowerCase, but toLowerCase()

Answer (score 0):

`.toLowerCase()` and `.include()` only work on strings. Make sure the parameter you are passing to the props is a string. In your code you are not passing any props so basically you are trying to execute those functions on an undefined type. Try this instead:

```
mount(<Provider store={store}>
        <MyComponent currentUser={user}/> //Specify 'user' before
      </Provider>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstable check if value exists and if role is string then apply some functions

```
this.props.currentUser && this.props.currentUser.role &&
this.props.currentUser.role.toString().toLowerCase().includes('admin') ? 'Yes included' or 'Not'
```

Be carefully too if you used **toLowerCase()** function do not compare with **Admin** compare with **admin**